# Could not find PyAudio check installation Error

Tags: django, pyaudio, portaudio, webfaction

I am trying to go live with my project and I am using PyAudio in it. I know that pyaudio requires port audio and it needs to be installed. All the requirements have been installed and pyaudio also installs successfully but when I try to execute the piece of code which uses pyaudio, I get the following error

```
    Could not find PyAudio; check installation
In the traceback we can see the following piece of code 

     import pyaudio
     except ImportError:
          raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
```

The website is being hosted at web faction.

Comment: This gets further into Python than I understand well, but do you need to run the application in the same virtual environment as in which you installed pyaudio?

Comment: No. In web faction I got no virtual environment

Comment: How are you serving/running your application? Is it a modwsgi app? Also, If you run `python` from the command line, then `import pyaudio`, do you get the same error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find pyaudio check installation in mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47121382/could-not-find-pyaudio-check-installation-in-mac)